# sed + how to remove the last string after specific character

Tags: linux, solaris, sed, ksh

how to remove the last string after "." character include the "." character itself

implementation can be with sed under Linux/Solaris operation system

example of IP address before change

```
      192.9.200.1     ( need to remove the .1 )
```

expected results

```
      192.9.200
```

other example

```
      100.2.2.101FFF
```

expected results

```
      100.2.2
```

Comment: just a side note, but using sed this way is advocating backtracking on the regex engine which is slow in case you need to change a huge amount of records on a regular basis.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

maybe with cut instead of sed?

```
echo "10.10.10.5" | cut -d. -f-3
```

if it has to be sed

```
echo "10.10.10.5fsdfdsf" | sed -e 's/\.[^\.]*$//'
```

Answer (score 8):

Why sed? How about manipulating with bash parameter expansion?

```
var="192.168.200.1"
echo ${var%.*}

192.168.200
```